# How to centralise logo between menu item in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, menuitem

I would like to centralise logo between menu item in Wordpress dt the7 theme, is there any solution to solve this problem? Because currently the menu was using build in layout which is logo at the top and menu item at below.

Answer (score 0):

I can't telling you exactly without seeing the problem, but you probably have to play with the line-height css property.

If you give us a clear example we will be able to help you more.